# Change job drop down filters to stick to be visible and filterable at the grid level

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

Currently when you hover over the location / keywords drop down in jobs you get a pop up asking for things such as the **type** of position as well as **location** information.  After you get your results it's quite not visible to see what selections were made.  I think these filters should stick to the actual grid of the search results right at the top, making it much easier to change.

Something to this effect (sorry I rushed this):

[image]

This way changes can be made on the fly and it's clearly visible what is being searched for.  The top search and location textboxes maintain there state and the drop downs or menu items (doesn't matter what you choose here) do the filtering.  For instance, when selecting "Within 50 miles" you are presented the mileage filter such as

within 50 miles, within 100 miles, within 500 miles, etc

The type drop down will filter the type of position (currently for contract, permanent, etc.).  As these change your grid results change and it's clearly visible what was being sought after.